# How to display a column that contains the current row index using ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview

I have the following class:

```
public class people
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string hobby { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to display a list like this:

```
no | name | hobby
-----------------------
01 | kim  | tv
02 | kate | pc
03 | kim  | tv
04 | kate | pc
```

The only way i know to achieve this is to change people class to

```
public class people
{
    public string no{ get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string hobby { get; set; }
}
```

and loop `List<people>` to set every `no` property.

Is there a better way to add an index number column?

Comment: Would be nice to have this built-in in the future!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve what you want by handling the ´FormatRow´ event like this:

```
objectListView1.FormatRow += delegate(object sender, FormatRowEventArgs args) {
    args.Item.Text = args.RowIndex.ToString();
};
```

This will show the zero-based index **on the first column** of the ObjectListView. If you want it to show as 01, 02... you can specify a format string and an offset like:

```
args.Item.Text = (args.RowIndex + 1).ToString("D2");
```

As a side note: Its not possible to achive this using the AspectGetter (which would be more elegant), because at the time its called, the row was not yet added to the OLV and thus has no index information.

```
// !!! won't work !!!
indexColumn.AspectGetter += delegate(object rowObject) {
    return objectListView1.IndexOf(rowObject).ToString();
};
```

Comment: What if my column is not the first one? I use an image column for first column so this is not working, I was using e.Item.SubItems[1].Text = (e.DisplayIndex + 1).ToString(); but it's ugly because I shouldn't use SubItems, so I changed it like (e.Model as MyModel).No = e.DisplayIndex + 1; but no matter what I set to "No" its not updating, I have UseNotifyPropertyChanged property true and firing PropertyChanged event in my setter but nothing happens

Comment: @ShinoLex: It is probably possible from inside the `FormatCell` event? But I haven't tried it.